# How create a custom category programmatically in magento 2.3.x

Tags: magento2, category, frontend

Hi im looking a custom module for insert a custom category on frontend, so i learn a some post to create that, ok i found this post https://community.magento.com/t5/Building-Extensions/create-module-to-add-new-Category-in-magento-2-2/td-p/95284 , ok now where i put this code?, i need create a one file external of the controller folder?

Comment: create file on root directory of your project